# Question about null-homotopic function

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

How to prove that every continuous function $f:M\to X$ from the Möbius strip $M$ into a simply connected space $X$ is null-homotopic? Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** The Möbius strip is homotopy equivalent to the circle.

Comment: To document Berci's comment, see [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148416/why-are-the-mobius-strip-and-the-boundary-of-a-klein-bottle-homotopy-equivalent).

Comment: Then, X is contractable and homotopy equivalent to R (with homotopy q). $S^1$ is simply connected, so there exists lifting p on $R$. Then $f=q p$ factorizes through contractible space, so $f$ is null-homotopic. Am I right?

Comment: $S^1$ is *not simply connected*: it has a loop which is not contractible within itself. Well, $f:M\to X$ can be composed to the homotopy equivalence map $S^1\to M$, this gives a loop in $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $M \simeq S^1$, take WLOG $f:S^1 \to X$. By definition a loop in $X$ is a path $g:I \to X$ such that $g(0)=g(1)$. Notice $S^1=I/\sim, 0\sim1$. So any map $f:S^1 \to X$ is just a loop and induces a loop in $\pi_1(X)$.

$\pi_1(X)=0$ so the loop has to be homotopic to a constant (trivial) loop and hence by definition null-homotopic.

Answer (score 2):

$$ \newcommand{\ra}[1]{\kern-1.5ex\xrightarrow{\ \ #1\ \ }\phantom{}\kern-1.5ex}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\bigg\downarrow\raise.5ex\rlap{\scriptstyle#1}} $$

The Möbius strip $M$ is the quotient space of $I^2$ obtained by the identification $(0,y)\sim(1,1-y)$.
\begin{array}{ccc}
I^2\times I &\ra d &I^2\\
\da{q\times Id} & &\da q\\
M\times I &\ra{\tilde d} &M
\end{array}
The square $I^2$ deformation retracts onto $I\times\left\{\frac12\right\}$ via $d((x,y),t)=tr(x,y)+(1-t)(x,y)=\left(x,\ \frac t2+(1-t)y\right)$ where $r(x,y)=\left(x,\frac12\right)$ is the retraction. Since $d((0,y),t)\sim d((x,1-y),t)$ (i.e. it respects the identification) and $q\times Id$ is a quotient map, it induces a deformation retraction $\tilde d$ of $M$ onto $\left(I\times\left\{\frac12\right\}\right)/\sim\ \approx S^1$. Composing $\tilde d$ with $f$ we obtain a homotopy between $f$ and $f\circ r$, the latter being the image of a circle in $X$. This circle can be contracted in $X$ since it is simply connected. Concatenating these homotopies gives a homotopy between $f$ and a constant map.